# Entity Framework Core 3.1 Return value (int) from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core-3.1

this returns -1, how can i get the actual return value from stored procedure?

here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Production].[Select_TicketQuantity]
    @Ticket NVARCHAR(25),
    @Reference NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @SQL nvarchar (4000)
    SET @SQL = 'select QARTCOL as Quantidade from D805DATPOR.GCARCCR1 where NCOLGIA = ' + @Ticket + ' AND NARTCOM = ''' + @Reference + ''''
    SET @SQL = N'select CONVERT(int,Quantidade) as Quantidade from OpenQuery(MACPAC, ''' + REPLACE(@SQL, '''', '''''') + ''')'
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

C# code

```
int? quantity= 0;
try
{
    quantity= await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC Production.Select_TicketQuantity @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { ticket, reference});
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError($"{ex}");
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

Comment: Consider to mark or to share the solution for it...

Answer (score 22):

`ExecuteSqlRawAsync` returns `the number of rows affected` for inserts, updates and deletes (-1 for selects).

If you don't want to alter your SP to introduce the `output parameter` you can use `SqlCommand`. `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` returns `The first column of the first row in the result set`:

```
using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "[Production].[Select_TicketQuantity]";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Ticket", ticket));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Reference", reference));
    quantity = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to create and use an [output parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure#returning-data-using-an-output-parameter), in your case:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [Production].[Select_TicketQuantity]
    @Ticket NVARCHAR(25),
    @Reference NVARCHAR(20),
    @Quantity int output
AS
BEGIN

declare @SQL nvarchar(4000) = 'select QARTCOL as Quantidade from D805DATPOR.GCARCCR1 where NCOLGIA = ''' + @Ticket + ''' AND NARTCOM = ''' + @Reference + ''''
select @Quantity = CONVERT(int, Quantidade)
  from OpenQuery(MACPAC, @SQL)

END
```

Then in C#:

```cs
int? quantity = 0;
var ticketParam = new SqlParameter("Ticket", ticket);
var referenceParam = new SqlParameter("Reference", reference);
var quantityParam = new SqlParameter("Quantity") { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
try
{
    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC Production.Select_TicketQuantity @Ticket, @Reference, @Quantity output", new[] { ticketParam, referenceParam, quantityParam });
    quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityParam.Value);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError($"{ex}");
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

Comment: this solution looks interesting but says invalid column on Quantidade at the convert and that expects a string at the @SQL in From Openquery

Comment: You can replace the text in the sproc with the original content, that was me doing a bit of playing.

Answer (score 5):

To add to what [AlbertK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59627588/4393935) already has written but by using `ExecuteSqlRaw`/`ExecuteSqlRawAsync`.

The best bet is to use `OUTPUT parameter` in your *Stored Procedure*.

Imagine a scenario where *reading* the **StatusCode** from a `stored procedure` is a necessity:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spIfUserExists (
    @Username VARCHAR(120),
    @StatusCode INT OUTPUT,
) AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[Users] WHERE Username=@Username)
        SET @StatusCode = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @StatusCode = 0;
END
```

You are not really returning anything but assigning an integer(`INT`) to the `output parameter` which will be available outside.

In your C# code, you need to create `SQLParameter` object with the `output parameter` name from your `stored procedure`.

```
SqlParameter StatusCode = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@StatusCode",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
    //Direction of this parameter is output.
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
 };
```

Finally, execute `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` with the required parameters for your SP.

Where `@p0,@p1..@pn` indicates the positional arguments of your stored procedure.

```
string Username = "MyRandomUsername";

using (var ctx = new UsersDbContext())
{
    await ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
      "spIfUserExists @p0, @StatusCode OUT",
      parameters: new object[] {
        Username,
        StatusCode,
      });
}

//StatusCode now contains the status code from the [spIfUserExists].
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(StatusCode.Value));
```

**The output parameters don't require the positional arguments like normal arguments do, e.g., `Username`.** Therefore, you don't need to pass `@p[n]` to the `OUTPUT arguments` but only providing them to the `parameters` list.

There is no difference in coding if you're to use `ExecuteSqlRaw`. You're only required to remove the `await` keyword to run `ExecuteSqlRaw` synchronously.

You can have more than one `output parameter` in your stored procedure with different datatypes. You only need to follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old but I have some stored procedures that use the following as the last line in the proc.

```sql
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

With that said I borrowed EF Core source code snippit and adjusted to allow for ExecuteScalar.
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs

```cs
    public static TResult ExecuteScalar<TResult>(this DbContext dbContext, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {            
        var facadeDependencies = (IRelationalDatabaseFacadeDependencies)((IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor)dbContext.Database).Dependencies;

        var rawSqlCommand = facadeDependencies.RawSqlCommandBuilder.Build(sql, parameters);
            
        var logger = facadeDependencies.CommandLogger;

        TResult result = (TResult)rawSqlCommand.RelationalCommand
                            .ExecuteScalar(
                                new RelationalCommandParameterObject(
                                    facadeDependencies.RelationalConnection,
                                    rawSqlCommand.ParameterValues,
                                    null,
                                    dbContext,
                                    logger, true));

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @AlbertK's answer you can add an extension to the DatabaseFacade type to get different types of scalar values returned.

Make sure you are using the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package rather than System.Data.SqlClient for your SqlParameter arguments otherwise you will receive a runtime exception. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16812

```
public static class DatabaseFacadeExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TResult> ExecuteScalarAsync<TResult>(
        this DatabaseFacade database, 
        String commandText, 
        CommandType commandType, 
        params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        TResult result;
        using (var cmd = database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            result = (TResult)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way which would not require you to modify your SP: Use the FromSqlRaw extension method of DbSet in order to get results in IQueryable.

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> RunSp<TResult>(this DbSet<TResult> dbSet, string storedProcedure, DbParameter[] parameters = null) where TResult : class
    {
        var paramNames = string.Empty;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            paramNames = string.Join(",", parameters.Select(a => a.ParameterName));
        }
        return dbSet.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC {storedProcedure} {paramNames}", parameters ?? new object[]{} );
    }
```

You need to define a DbSet in your context with the result type you want to get:

```
[Keyless]
    public class TestSpRecord
    {
        public int Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Usage would be like:

```
var resultList = testCtx.TestSpRecords.RunSp("EchoParams", new DbParameter[] {  new SqlParameter("@Param1",10),new SqlParameter("@Param2","text")});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this conventional method to get a  single integer value from sp.

```
var commandText=  "EXEC Production.Select_TicketQuantity"+string.format(" @p0={0}, @p1={1}", ticket, reference)

using (var command = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = commandText;
                    dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
                    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (result.HasRows == true)
                        {
                            if (result.Read())
                            {
                                var returnInteger = result.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : result.GetInt32(0);
                                result.Close();
                                return returnInteger;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    return 1;
                }
```